# kind cluster principals have list create privileges on pod objects

Tags: kubernetes

I have installed kind cluster in local windows system, by default i can able to list and create the pod objects using below commands i can able understand i have the access to create and list the pod.

What know which user its belongs to list and create pod, how to verify which user its running below command without any username.

```
kubectl auth can-i list pod
yes

kubectl auth can-i create pod
yes
```

With specific user bob i have created ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding

```
kubectl auth can-i --list --as bob
Resources                                       Non-Resource URLs   Resource Names   Verbs
selfsubjectreviews.authentication.k8s.io        []                  []               [create]
selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io   []                  []               [create]
selfsubjectrulesreviews.authorization.k8s.io    []                  []               [create]
pods                                            []                  []               [get list watch]
```